# Replace number with a random number of same amount of digits

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a string containing some numbers and to relace every single digit with a sigle random number.
E.g. "111" should be replaced with 3 random numbers between 0-9 that are concatenated like "364".

My idea was to match a number, get the number of digits, calculate as many random numbers and concatenate them to finally replace my matched number:

```
test <- "this is 1 example 123. I like the no.37"
gsub("([0-9])", paste0(sample(0:9, nchar("\\1")), collapse = ""), test)
```

My goal would be to have a string where every single digit is replaced by a random digit. E.g.

```
"this is 3 an example 628. I like the no.09"
```

I tried some approaches but can't find a good solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `gsubfn` library, it will make things simpler:

```
library(gsubfn)
test <- "this is 1 example 123. I like the no.37"
gsubfn("[0-9]+", ~ paste0(sample(0:9, nchar(x)), collapse = ""), test)
[1] "this is 8 example 205. I like the no.37"
```

Here, `gsubfn` will match all 1 or more digits in the string (see the `[0-9]+` pattern). Then, the matches are passed to the callback where `nchar` gets the real value of the captured substring (the digit substrings).